TPN API integration - SoapFault exception: [Client] looks like we got no XML document
When I sent XML data in the Guzzle it worked but when I implemented that on SoapClient it did not work.
Guzzle Code
$client = new Client();
$headers = [
    'Content-Type' => 'text/xml; charset=utf-8',
    'SOAPAction' => 'http://tempuri.org/IThirdPartyServices/GetConsignment'
];
$body = '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
            <soapenv:Header/>
            <soapenv:Body>
                <tem:GetConsignment>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <tem:userName>xxx</tem:userName>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <tem:password>xxx</tem:password>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <tem:consignmentNumber>85068878</tem:consignmentNumber>
                </tem:GetConsignment>
            </soapenv:Body>
        </soapenv:Envelope>';


$options = [
    'headers' => [
        'Content-Type' => 'text/xml; charset=utf-8',
        'SOAPAction' => 'http://tempuri.org/IThirdPartyServices/GetConsignment'
    ],
    'body' => $body,
];

$response = $client->request('POST', 'http://dev.tpnconnect.com:3268/ThirdPartyServices.svc?wsdl', $options);
echo ((string) $response->getBody());

SoapClient Code
$url = "http://dev.tpnconnect.com:3268/ThirdPartyServices.svc?wsdl";

$soap_client = new \SoapClient($url, ['exceptions' => true, 'trace' => true]);

$soap_client->__setLocation('http://dev.tpnconnect.com/');

$params = [
    "userName" => "xxx",
    "password" => "xxx",
    "consignmentNumber" => "85068878",
];


try {
    $response = $soap_client->getConsignment($body);

    var_dump($response);exit;
}
catch(\SoapFault $fault){
  echo $fault;exit;
}

Error Message
SoapFault exception: [Client] looks like we got no XML document in ....
The function $soap_client->__getLastRequest(); generates following result which I think is correct.
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://tempuri.org/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<ns1:GetConsignment>
<ns1:userName>xxx</ns1:userName>
<ns1:password>xxx</ns1:password>
<ns1:consignmentNumber>85068878</ns1:consignmentNumber>
</ns1:GetConsignment>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>

